# Flickering in Chrome when using on click fadeOut on isotope

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, fadeout, jquery-isotope

I'm building a website at http://www.gablabelle.com and when you click on an image thumbnail it flickers before fading out... But this is only in Google Chrome, not in Firefox and Safari.

What could cause this and is there a way for me to solve this issue?

```
       <div id="streamwrapper">
            <div id="sidebar">  
            </div>
            <div id="stream">
                <article id="509">
                    <a class="ajaxed" href="#"><img src="#" alt="" /></a>
                </article>
           </div> 
      </div>
```

...

```
$("a.ajaxed").on("click",function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        postid = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        $("#streamwrapper").fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
                data: ({
                    action : "get_all_images",
                    post_id: postid
                    }),
                success:function(data){
                    $("#post-container").append(data);
                },
                error:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: doesn't flicker for me, chrome 21.0.1180.89 m on Win7.

Comment: Using Chrome 21.0.1180.89, I don't see any flickering happening. Are you sure it isn't your internet connection?

Comment: Also, instead of fading out the `#streamwrapper`, have you thought of fading in a solid black `div` with a higher z-index ? (that way the images themselves aren't being faded)

Comment: Hmmm that's weird! @ahren Well I need the height of the page to adapt to the new content.

Comment: @A.M.K are you on Windows too?

Comment: Yes, but Windows 8 (Consumer Preview).

Comment: I guess I'll have to test again. thanks guys I'll come back with an update.

Comment: Upgrading Google Chrome from 18.0.1025.165 to Version 21.0.1180.89 solved the issue. :-| ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading Google Chrome from 18.0.1025.165 to Version 21.0.1180.89 solved the issue. :-| ;-)